# django validationerror password field error

Tags: python, django

i just create and form to let people register
the forms.py is here

```
from django import forms
from django.conf import settings
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model



def lowercase_email(email):
        """
        Normalize the address by lowercasing the domain part of the email
        address.
        """
        email = email or ''
        try:
            email_name, domain_part = email.strip().rsplit('@', 1)
        except ValueError:
            pass
        else:
            email = '@'.join([email_name.lower(), domain_part.lower()])
        return email

class SignupForm (forms.ModelForm):

    username =forms.CharField( 
        label='username',required=True,max_length=20,min_length=3)
    email = forms.EmailField( 
        label='email',required=True)
    password =forms.CharField( 
        label='password',required=True,max_length=20,min_length=6)
    confirm_password= forms.CharField(
        label='confirm_password',required=True,max_length=20,min_length=6)

    class Meta:
        model = get_user_model()
        fields = ("username","email","password",)


    def clean_email(self):
        UserModel = get_user_model()
        email=self.cleaned_data["email"]
        lower_email=lowercase_email(email)
        try:
            UserModel._default_manager.get(email=lower_email)
        except UserModel.DoesNotExist:
            return lower_email
        raise forms.ValidationError("this email is already used ")

    def clean_password(self):

        password = self.cleaned_data["password"]
        confirm_password = self.cleaned_data["confirm_password"]
        if  password != confirm_password:
            raise forms.ValidationError("password not same")
        return password
```

this can not work,it show

```
KeyError at /accounts/signup/
'confirm_password'
Request Method: POST
Request URL:    http://localhost:8000/accounts/signup/
Django Version: 1.6
Exception Type: KeyError
Exception Value:    
'confirm_password'
Exception Location: C:\pro1\mysns\sns\accounts\forms.py in clean_password, line 50
Python Executable:  C:\Python33\python.exe
```

ok now i just change the password clean method to
def clean_confirm_password(self)
and now it work ,

```
def clean_confirm_password(self):

            password = self.cleaned_data["password"]
            confirm_password = self.cleaned_data["confirm_password"]
            if  password != confirm_password:
                raise forms.ValidationError("password not same")
            return confirm_password
```

any one can tell me why ? thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should check them in `clean` method, then you can get them both from `form.cleaned_data`.

Or change the `clean_password` method to:

```
def clean_password(self):
    # use data instead of cleaned_data
    password = self.data["password"]
    confirm_password = self.data["confirm_password"]
    if  password != confirm_password:
        raise forms.ValidationError("password not same")
    return confirm_password
```

`clean_xxx` methods are called in the order of field declarations, `password` is before `confirm_password`, so when `clean_password` is called, `form.cleaned_data['confirm_password']` has not been set.